# Unable to publish test results during execution of Visual Studio Test task in VNext build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

During VNext build the test results are not published after the test cases are executed, logs indicate the following warning:

Executing the powershell script: E:\Builds\agent\tasks\VSTest\1.0.30\VSTest.ps1

##[debug]Calling Invoke-VSTest for all test assemblies

Working folder: E:\Builds\agent_work\3

Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "E:\Builds\agent_work\3\s\TestAutomation\UnitTestProject3\UnitTestProject3\bin\Release\TCSuiteFolder\TestComplete11Test1.tc11Test"  /logger:trx

Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

Passed   TestComplete11Test1

Results File: E:\Builds\agent_work\3\TestResults\TFS04 2016-07-18 14_31_47.trx

Total tests: 1. Passed: 1. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.

Test Run Successful.

Test execution time: 26.5749 Minutes

Publishing Test Results...

> [warning]Invalid results file. Please make sure the Test Result Format
>   field in the task matches the result format of the file:
>   E:\Builds\agent_work\3\TestResults\TFS04 2016-07-18 14_31_47.trx

Note: Test scripts generated using Test Complete tool are executed as suggested in the following url: https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/79180/

Also is it possible to execute the Test Complete scripts using "Run Functional tests using test agent" task in TFS Release Management?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Regards,

Santhosh

Comment: What's the detail info of the .trx file? Make sure you have installed VS2015 on your build server.

Comment: We have installed VS 2015 on the build machine. Are you referring to Error info section in the .trx file when you ask about .detail info?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, the test complete tool is 3rd party tool. Not sure Whether this impact.

Comment: Does your build agent meet the requirement here: https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/73370/?

Comment: Yes all the requirements are met as mentioned, the test script execution also succeeds except that the test result publish fails.

Comment: Is there any other error message during the publish? Can you set the variable "system.debug" to "true" and queue the build agent, and then shared the entire logs?